Custom equations alignement
I'm writing a math handout for school wich obviously contains a lot of math :)
I use different math enviorment to write down my equations such as:

\begin{equation}
$$ <Math> $$
\[ <Math> \]

And I also tried \begin{flalign*}.
Since I'm having some problems understanding how to use them properly and since I want to do a very specific thing i figured that the best way to solve the problem was asking here.
I need to write some equation without numbering them. Those equation should be centered in the document (So using simply $$ <Math> $$ already solve this problem)
Then I need to write some numbered equation. Those equations should be aligned to the left.
In a previous document I wrote, I used \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} and that actually worked.
Now it's not!
Since using the above mentioned environments often dosen't work properly i want to know if I can implement some new commands to achieve my goal and write my equation the way I want.
Imma share with you a sample of the preamble of the code.
Thank you all so much in advance
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\end{document}

PS: I use Overleaf to compile my LaTeX documents.

$$...$$ is not LaTeX and does not follow LaTeX configuration rules so should not be used. This requirement "Those equations should be aligned to the left." sounds very strange.

You mention that the main body of the document is in a file called MyFile.tex and remark that "using the above mentioned environments often doesn't work properly". As we have no idea what's in MyFile.tex, how are we supposed to help you fix your math typesetting issues? Please edit your query and post a few sample displayed equations that are giving you trouble.

In MyFile.Tex are supposed to be some text and some equation.
I need to work in the preampble i guess in order to achive the goal

Your preamble looks fine. It's the equations that are (in all likelihood) coded in a faulty manner.

Please also consult the posting Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$? for a thorough discussion of why one shouldn't use $$...$$ in LaTeX documents.

OK thanks I'm gonna read it
